# Dynamically create after_add and after_remove callbacks for has_many or habtm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, has-many-through

Is there a way to dynamically add `after_add` and `after_remove` callbacks to an existing `has_many` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship?

For example, suppose I have models `User`, `Thing`, and a join model `UserThingRelationship`, and the `User` model is something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_thing_relationships
  has_many :things, :through => :user_thing_relationships
end
```

I'd like to be able to, in a module that extends `User`, add `:after_add` and `:after_remove` callbacks to the `User.has_many(:things, ...)` relationship.  I.e., have something like

```
module DoesAwesomeStuff
  def does_awesome_stuff relationship, callback
    # or however this can be achieved...
    after_add(relationship) callback
    after_remove(relationship) callback
  end
end
```

So that

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_thing_relationships
  has_many :things, :through => :user_thing_relationships

  does_awesome_stuff :things, :my_callback
  def my_callback; puts "awesome"; end
end
```

Is effectively the same as

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_thing_relationships
  has_many :things, :through => :user_thing_relationships, :after_add => :my_callback, :after_remove => :my_callback

  def my_callback; puts "awesome"; end
end
```

This can be done pretty effectively for adding `after_save`, etc, callbacks to the model that's being extended, since `ActiveRecord::Base#after_save` is just a class method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to come up with the following by using [ActiveRecord::Reflection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html):

```
module AfterAdd
  def after_add rel, callback
    a = reflect_on_association(rel)
    send(a.macro, rel, a.options.merge(:after_add => callback))
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend AfterAdd

  has_many :user_thing_relationships
  has_many :things, :through => :user_thing_relationships

  after_add :things, :my_callback

  def my_callback
    puts "Hello"
  end
end
```

I don't want to answer my own question, so I won't give myself answer credit if someone else can come up with a better solution in the next few days.

Comment: Sorry for burying this out, but afaik, your callback will leak out, no? I.e. if two threads were to run after_add at the same time, you wouldn't know which callback is valid?

Comment: There is a drawback of your method. If it's a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association, you will call `has_and_belongs_to_many` twice and this will define an extra `dependent: :delete` for `user_thing_relationships`

Answer (score 13):

The easiest would be

```
User.after_add_for_things << lambda do |user, thing| 
  Rails.logger.info "#{thing} added to #{user}"
end
```

Note: No longer works in Rails 7 (thanks to Andrew Hodgkinson for pointing this out)

Comment: i'm curious on how you were able to find out about this dynamic feature

Comment: This feature is located in `define_callback` in `lib/active_record/associations/builder/collection_association.rb`. (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/collection_association.rb)

Comment: *IMPORTANT*: Note that this mechanism is gone in Rails 7 and it looks like it was considered internal previously. The relevant module has `:nodoc:` all over it now, so it's pretty explicit. Change was in https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/bfcac1359e6a1848c07ced1b301a339b54fb260d#diff-0e0ba9f548037ce5d4f147573d47ac5fe619c12f7ebb2d2f24090306a2bf7133.